# How to mock a RestTemplate Exchange spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, automated-tests, mockito, junit5

I have tried many ways to mock the restTemplate exchange, but the mock is not happening, the actual exchange keeps on calling and gives me url not valid exception.

My CallRestService method is below

```java
public class Util{
    
    public static ResponseEntity<String> callRestService(JSONObject reqJsonObj,HttpHeaders headers, String url, HttpMethod method, boolean isAuto){
        ResponseEntity<String> re=null;
        try{
            HttpEntity<String> entity=null;
            entity=new HttpEntity<>(String.valueOf(reqJsonObj),headers);
            RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
            re=restTemplate.exchange(url,method,entity,String.class);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And My Mock is below:

```java
public class UtilTest{
    @InjectMocks
    Util util;
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    ResponseEntity res=mock(ResponseEntity.class);

    @Test
    public void test(){
        //ResponseEntity<String> entity=new ResponseEntity<String>("anySt",HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpEntity.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())
        ).thenReturn(res);
        Util.callRestService(json,headers,url,HttpMethod.POST,false);
    }
}
```

I also tried to return the commented response Entity. but always got exception in exchange.

What i understand about mocking is the actual exchange method will not be called, then how am i getting resttemplate exchange exception.

if any inputs required pls comment.

Thanks for the support.

> UPDATE:
> I tried with changing the static method to non static but kept the test case as is. But i get the same error

Comment: the exception says : Exception occurs while calling REST Service - uri is not absolute.

Comment: why everything static? try injecting mock via constructor

Comment: i can't change the method being static, but I kept the  RestTemplate declaration outside during research. The static method are done by project team

Comment: you can not inject mocks because rest template initiliaze in function. If it is done by project team, they are responsible for writing test for this code.

Comment: thanks @fuat, i was putting the resttemplate declaration outside the function. and running in background the test actually passed.

Comment: any idea whether it will work even if the method is static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is resolved when I update the method to non static and move the *Resttemplate* declaration outside the method.

Updated code is below, if anyone found it useful.

Method changes :

```java
public class Util{
    private RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
    public ResponseEntity<String> callRestService(JSONObject reqJsonObj,HttpHeaders headers, String url, HttpMethod method, boolean isAuto){
        ResponseEntity<String> re=null;
        try{
            HttpEntity<String> entity=null;
            entity=new HttpEntity<>(String.valueOf(reqJsonObj),headers);
            re=restTemplate.exchange(url,method,entity,String.class);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the mock with verify :

```java
public class UtilTest{
    @InjectMocks
    Util util;
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        ResponseEntity<String> entity=new ResponseEntity<String>("anySt",HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpEntity.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())
        ).thenReturn(entity);

        Util.callRestService(json,headers,url,HttpMethod.POST,false);

        Mockito.verify(restTemplate,times(1)).exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpEntity.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi using the implementation above, I am getting HTTP URL must not be null error message. Any ideas?